# Cannot fire php -v from terminal

Tags: php, macos, xampp, macos-catalina

I have uninstalled XAMPP because recently I found that php comes install by default in macOS. My MacOs version is Catalina. So whenever I fire any php command from cli it gives me Library not loaded but strange thing is it returns XAMP path.

[image]

Comment: when you uninstalled, did you update your PATH variable (or the OS X equiv.)?

Comment: Can you update and add your PATH variable? Would also be interesting to see the result of `which php` as well as the configuration in your `php.ini`, if it contains reference to this library.

Comment: @LouisCharette in my experience, the OS X which usage sucked compared to Linux - might give false information, not sure if `find / -name "php.ini"` works on OS X though..

Comment: Indeed, `type php` would probably better in this case...

Comment: No I did not updated my path but I think never set the path to my XAMP application because even when I had xampp installed and running i got the /usr/local path when I typed 'which php'

Comment: @treyBake But I did fired this command "PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Which PHP do you actually want to run? The one Apple supplied with macOS? One installed by **homebrew**? Or your XAMPP one?

Comment: The one supplied with macOS @Mark Setchell

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/php -v`

Comment: Ok, will try tomorrow and post the updates.

Comment: @MarkSetchell no it's not working. It returns the same thing.